# How to fetch AWS secrets at Express app startup and ensure they are available across application?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-secrets-manager

Initially, I had my credentials in the env variable for my Express JS app, so I was able to fetch the credentials in any module required. Now I am moving all my credentials to AWS Secrets Manager, which means I will have to fetch the secrets asynchronously.

How can I access the credentials across my application?

Here is what I have done so far:

`get-secrets.ts`

```
let allSecrets = {};

const getSecretsFromAws = async () => {
    // If secrets are found, returns the secrets object.
    // else returns {}
};

export const initSecrets = async () => {
  allSecrets = await getSecretsFromAws();
  return allSecrets;
};

export const getSecrets = () => {
  return allSecrets;
};
```

`main.ts`

```
// some routes and middlewares defined at the top

const startServer = async () => {
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: schema,
    resolvers,
    context: graphQlMiddleware,
  });
  await initSecrets(); // Load secrets from AWS Secrets Manager
  await server.start();
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Expense-core listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
};

startServer();
```

`some-config.ts`

```
const resolvedSecrets = getSecrets();
console.log('resolvedSecrets:', resolvedSecrets);
```

**The Problem:**

When I run my application, resolvedSecrets in some-config.ts is logging an empty object {}. It seems that initSecrets() in main.ts is executed after resolvedSecrets is accessed, leading to this issue.

**My Question:**

How can I ensure that my AWS secrets are fetched and fully resolved before any other part of my application (like routes, middleware, or configurations) is executed?

Comment: As you only answered yourself, make the initSecrets() to run first